# How to use dynamic struct reference within multithread process in Rust?

Tags: multithreading, rust, rayon

I am trying to simulate and transform data with multithreading, while leaving to user what kind of transformation to use, as long as it implements my `Transformation` trait.

I understand broadly why complier doesn't like to use raw `Transformation` in `.map()` method, but I wanted to know the best way to approach this problem in Rust.

I am using `rayon` here but any other suggestion will be also appreciated.

```
use rayon::prelude::*;

pub trait Transformation {
    fn result(&self, input: &f64) -> f64; 
}
pub struct Division { 
    pub by: f64 
}
impl Transformation for Division {
    fn result(&self, input: &f64) -> f64 {
        input / self.by
    }
}

fn simulate_and_transform(paths_num: &usize, trans: &dyn Transformation) -> Vec<f64> {
    (0..*paths_num)
        .into_par_iter()
        .map(|_| trans.result(&rand::random::<f64>()))
        .collect()
}

fn main() {
    let div = Division {by: 2.0};
    let paths = 100;
    let sims = simulate_and_transform(&paths, &div);
    println!("Samples: {}, {}, {}", sims[3], sims[56], sims[99]);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is only a simple problem here: you haven't required that the `Transformation` is safe to use from multiple threads. That is expressed using [the `Sync` trait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Sync.html). You can either require it for all implementors of the trait:

```rust
pub trait Transformation: Sync {
```

or you can require it when it's used:

```
fn simulate_and_transform(paths_num: &usize, trans: &(dyn Transformation + Sync)) -> Vec<f64> {
```

Either of these changes will allow your program to compile.